# what's wrong with the following htaccess rules

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

Hi I got an amazing (?) work to fix the error on a site. It was a HTTP 500 error.
It is caused by the htaccess file. But I can't figure out what's wrong with the code. here is the code.

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php


# The rules below basically say that if the file exists in the tree, just
# serve it; otherwise, go to index.php. This is more future-proof for your
# site, because if you start adding more and more content types, you don't
# need to alter the .htaccess to accomodate them.
# This is an important concept for the Front Controller Pattern which the
# ZF MVC makes use of.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
Redirect 301 /platforms/mt4-ecn http://example.com/
Redirect 301 /partnerships/mt4-to-mt4-bridge http://example.com/

<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/aaaecn/public_html 
</IfModule>
<Files php.ini> 
order allow,deny 
deny from all 
</Files>
```

this redirect rules are for zend framework, But I don't have any experience in working with that framework.

I commented all lines and tried now the 500 error is fixed. So I filtered it down by uncommenting.

> RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

this line is causing the error, but removing this giving invalid redirects and 404 errors. what can I do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(partnerships/mt4-to-mt4-bridge|platforms/mt4-ecn)/?$ / [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Check your Apache error.log and paste the full error text here.

Comment: My bad, The problem is not even inside this code. they are intentionally redirecting the site to another site inside the public folders htaccess file. Just now noticed that. I removed that and this site works.. I still can't understand why such a mess happened here.. thanks for your help anyway..

Comment: Ok glad to know. However `Redirect 301 ...` rules after `RewriteRule` lines is still incorrect. You should have 301 rules before generic catch-all rule as I suggested above.